# Why am I unable to add nodes to my adjacency list?

Tags: java

It says that I must initialize the `adj`but it doesn't work. I know something is majorly wrong. I also tried using an ArrayList inside an ArrayList and that didn't work either. What's wrong you reckon?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class AdjacencyList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter nodes below like (u,v):");

        //Create List
        ArrayList<Integer>[] adj;


        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            String nodes = in.nextLine();
            String[] data = nodes.split(",");

            String u    = data[0]; 
            String v    = data[1];
            int inNode  = Integer.parseInt(u);
            int outNode =Integer.parseInt(v);

            adj[inNode]  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            adj[inNode].add(outNode);
            System.out.println("Added to list");

        }

        //print nodes and then their corresponding list
        System.out.println(adj[1]);




    }

}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>[] adj;` Are you sure you want an array of `ArrayList`s?

Comment: Nope, that'd be too costly, so not at this stage.

Comment: But that's what you're doing.

Comment: Let's suppose I'd want this to work at this stage, what would be the solution. The problem lies in two lies (according to Eclipse errors) above the "Added to list" sysout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you really want an *array* of `ArrayList`s, you should initialize it like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] adj = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[SIZE];
```

Comment: Type mismatch. I need to create the ArrayList for each unique node iteratively in the loop so I am doing adj[inNode]  = (ArrayList<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[2];

Comment: You shouldn't be getting *type mismatch* with this line. You are initializing *each* element in the array in the loop. Yet, you need to initialize the *array* too!

Comment: I did that, doesn't work. Type mismatch does appear during the loop initialization process and that was the original problem.

Comment: I've just tried the code and it works fine. Please post the full error.

Comment: Why don't you post the code snippet(s) in the answer to make things more clearer for me. If it works obviously.

Comment: Just change `ArrayList<Integer>[] adj;` to what I proposed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47587/discussion-between-maroun-maroun-and-ali-gajani)